# Two jQuery File Upload widgets on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I'm using jquery jQuery File Upload plugin (blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload images but I want to add another fileupload widget to download other files. Is it possible to have two widgets on the same page?

Thanks

Comment: just add plugins refrence to your page and wtih jQuery selectors make file upload section with defferent plugins.

Comment: All genius is simple!! Thanks a lot